# what is the difference in /# and ~# for a root user?

Tags: root, su

I know that $ is a non-root user and # indicates a root user, similarly trying to understand the basic difference in the representation for a root user with the syntax  "/#" and "~#".

```
root@a145f139efec:/# pwd
/
root@a145f139efec:/# whoami
root
root@a145f139efec:/# su -
root@a145f139efec:~# pwd
/root
root@a145f139efec:~# whoami
root
root@a145f139efec:~#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both symbols before the `#` represent the current directory you're in. In your first example you are in the `/` directory. Entering `su -` then changes you to root's home directory, which is `/root`. The `~` symbolizes the home directory.